# string argument without an encoding with postgres and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

I am commiting objects to my PostgreSQL database and I try to query it, throws the error
I am using flask-sqlalchemy.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_populate_questions.py", line 12, in <module>
    question = question_manager.get(id=1).first()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3397, in first
    ret = list(self[0:1])
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3171, in __getitem__
    return list(res)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 101, in instances
    cursor.close()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 81, in instances
    rows = [proc(row) for row in fetch]
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 81, in <listcomp>
    rows = [proc(row) for row in fetch]
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 580, in _instance
    _populate_full(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\loading.py", line 726, in _populate_full
    dict_[key] = getter(row)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\sqltypes.py", line 1707, in process
    value = impl_processor(value)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\sqltypes.py", line 945, in process
    value = bytes(value)
TypeError: string argument without an encoding
```

I will describe down here how it is modelled and how I am making the connection.

```
class Questions(db.Model):
    """ Question model """

    __tablename__ = "questions"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    question_url = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    question_video_url = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=True)
    category = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    topics = db.Column(db.PickleType, nullable=False)
    difficulty = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    problem_type = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    percentile = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    answer = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    prompt = db.Column(db.String(1500), nullable=True)
```

Topics is a PickleType, that is pickled as a list of n values.
Then I have a manager on other file, just to be able to iterate through the db via code, and not needing to be making the API requests always.
Here is the base manager:

```
class BaseManager(ABC):
    """
    Base Manager object.
    Abstract base class to query the backend.
    """

    @abstractproperty
    def _model(self):
        pass

    def __init__(self, db_uri=constants.DB_URI):
        self.engine = create_engine(constants.DB_URI,  client_encoding='utf8')
        self.get_session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)

    def get(self, **filters):
        conditions = []
        for attr_name, value in filters.items():
            if value is not None:
                conditions.append(getattr(self._model, attr_name) == value)
        session = self.get_session()
        ret_values = session.query(self._model).filter(*conditions)
        session.close()
        return ret_values

    def add(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = self._model(*args, **kwargs)
        session = self.get_session()
        session.add(obj)
        session.commit()
        session.close()
```

Then, what I actually am trying to do, that is first adding a question to the table:

```
question_manager = QuestionManager()

for question in pd.read_csv('test_questions.csv').to_dict('records'):
    user_manager.add(**question)
```

To iterate through the csv to add the questions, I am using pandas and parsing it to a list of dicts.

Then when I try to get a question from the table.

```
question_manager = QuestionManager()
question = question_manager.get(id=1)
print(question.first()) # Here is where the error mentioned occurs
```

Sorry for the long code pasting, I tried to give all the context to the community help me solve this issue!
Can you guys know what is going on?

PS: when I tried with a simple local DB, sqlite, it worked, so I think is something related to postgres specifically.

Comment: just edited with the complete error

Comment: Have you got an example of a record that causes this error (that is, can you provide sample data)?